# Number of days in a normal year expressed with five consecutive positive integers

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, no-computers

Given

$D$ is the total number of days in a normal year

$a$, $b$ are positive integers

$P$, $Q$, $R$, $S$, $T$ are consecutive integers

Figure them out by combining the following six expressions into 2 equations involving D. Valid solution is the one that gives numerical values for all a b P Q R S T.

X is the missing operator

> $ D ^ { a x b }$  x  $P^a$  X $Q^a$  X $R^a$  X  $S^a$ X $T^a$

You are allowed to use operators

> $+$ $-$ $\times$ $/$ $($ $)$ $=$

Comment: Just to clarify do you mean for this puzzle to be asking the solver to sub in those signs in any way that creates valid equation?

Comment: Yes..valid equation(s)..you can sub in the allowed signs between each separate term

Comment: @weathervane....times should be removed

Comment: In place of times, allowed operators can be putin

Comment: Thx..it would be better, they are all in one line

Comment: I would edit it to clarify and let me know weather it adds any further clarity

Comment: Excuse me, but what is a valid solution? Can you please post an example which is a valid (but incorrect) solution?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Out.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think you mean VTC there?

Comment: @Uvc It's bad form to revise the specifications of the original puzzle after an answer has already been given. I'd suggest you roll back to before you added the "2 equations" part. And I also agree with Weather Vane that it's not clear what we're supposed to do. Do you mean to find two equations such that each equation *separately* contains all those expressions or when *combined* contain them all? I.e. would $ D^{ab} = P^a + Q^a $ and $ D^{ab} = R^a + S^a + T^a $ be considered valid?

Comment: 365**3=20**3+21**3+..as an example

Comment: @pilsnot3..I am very sorry to cause this confusion...is there a way to delete it as I should have specified that a be greater than 1

Comment: Have you been thinking about [this comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83700/can-you-find-this-abundant-dad-and-his-six-prime-sons#comment242945_83700)? You are becoming a prolific puzzle-maker, and some are very good, but is there some scope for you to review them as a **puzzle solver**, before posting?

Comment: In addition to that, I recommend checking out the [sandbox](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5276/57742) over on meta. It's not mandatory to do so nowadays, but if you post any puzzles/riddles you're thinking about over there, the community will provide feedback on what needs to be improved *before* it hits the main page

Comment: Main problem is I am very poor for matter..when I transfer it from daily puzzle creation book,, meaning is getting lost...all the confusion would have been avoided if I have put question marks where the math operators go.. I hope to get better by wearing a puzzle solver hat prior to posting and anticipate the ambiguities

Comment: On top of what @WeatherVane said, I think number puzzles of good quality are especially difficult to create because you have to prove that the intended solution is the only solution (in some way or another) while also keeping it interesting, unique and understandable. How about you try branching out into other types of puzzle while keeping your number puzzles on the back-burner so that you have plenty of time to notice any mistakes!

Comment: Edited to reflect my original intention..because of formatting skills, I regret that I have caused lot of confusion

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this can be solved fairly trivially.

We are given that $D = 365$.

If we take $a=1$ and $b=2$, then $D^{ab} = D^2 = 365^2 = 133225$.

Now, since $a=1$, we just need five consecutive integers that sum to $133225$.

We can easily find those by taking $133225 \div 5 = 26645$, and then taking the two preceding and two following integers.

Then we have
$P^a = 26643^1 = 26643$
$Q^a = 26644^1 = 26644$
$R^a = 26645^1 = 26645$
$S^a = 26646^1 = 26646$
$T^a = 26647^1 = 26647$

So the final solution is

> $$365^{1\times2} = 26643^1 + 26644^1 + 26645^1 + 26646^1 + 26647^1$$

Comment: The question asks for two equations.

Comment: @WeatherVane It didn't when I was typing this up.  It was just changed.

Comment: You are right, that was slipped in after my last edit.

Comment: Edited to provide clarification and true to my original intent of the puzzle